# Want to change the default wrapping behavior of char* in swig java

Tags: java, c++, c, memory, swig

So there's this line in the swig documentation

> When `char *` members of a structure are wrapped, the contents are assumed to be dynamically allocated using malloc or new (depending on whether or not SWIG is run with the -c++ option). When the structure member is set, the old contents will be released and a new value created.

I don't want the old contents to be released from memory because I'm using some sort of `char*` buffer, and I also need the default setter. I can use the `%ignore <field>` to overwrite the getter but then I'll lose the default setter.
Can someone please help? Thanks.